# Cannot get captcha to work

Tags: captcha, ee

I'm trying to use the new channel form captcha functionality, and I never get the fields displayed, apparently because the {if captcha} conditional always fails.  However, like one of the blog posts I saw, when I take the conditional off, I do get a display of the {captcha} image.

I have followed the instructions and have Allow Guest posts set to yes, Guest Captcha set to yes, And I yave Use TrueType Font set to Yes and that font is there in the {site_url}/images/captchas directory.  I just re-affirmed for the second time that my images/captchas directory is set to 0777, although that may not be valid as it's a Windows server.  I don't know how to check the GD library, but every other aspect of EE seems to work fine.

I am not able to see any evidence of GD library.  As it's a windows server, I'm not sure where to look.  Anyone know where in the GUI, or elsewhere, I can see that?

Comment: Does your local environment pass the server requirements test? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html#server-compatibility-wizard

Answer (score 2):

If you can see the CAPTCHA sometimes then you don't have a problem with permissions or the GD library.

Are you logged in to the site/CP when you *can't* see the CAPTCHA? There is a setting to show CAPTCHAs only to users that aren't logged in.

Comment: This is likely it. OP, try logging out or requiring CAPTCHA for members as well.